# Mapbox GL JS Marker Collision?

Tags: mapbox, markers, mapbox-gl-js

I want to make it such that my markers at higher zoom levels are replaced by one marker. This is similar to the cluster function, which I have also not been able to make work either. I believe that this would be much easier than the cluster function to make work, and I do not necessarily want to express how many data points there are in any given area. From my understanding the collision function is fairly easy to create but I am unsure how. I'm using custom icons, added from `map.addsource(places, {`. I've played with the CSS a bit and that has not worked. The collision problems did not seem to exist when I was using style/layer based icons rather than custom ones. My project is adapted from the mapbox tutorial for building stores.

Comment: Markers and Symbols are different things. Could could clarify which you are using? In the title you say Marker, but later on your say you're using icons via addSource which implies Symbol.

Comment: I follow the [tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/help/building-a-store-locator/#add-custom-markers) for creating custom markers, so I assume that they are markers.